# Bounded Linear Functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I have got stuck on this problem for quite some time now. Let $f$ be a measureable function that belongs to $X$, where $X$ is either $L^p$ ($1\leq p<\infty$) or $C_0$. Let $X_0=\{g \in X: \int_X|fg|\,dm<\infty\}$. Define $T_f:X_0\to C$ by 
$T_f(g)=\int_Xfg\,dm$.Then prove that $T_f$ is bounded if and only if $f\in L^\infty$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you clarify you mean by "$g$ in $X$"? It seems that you mean for $g$ to be a function on $X$. Also do you have any thoughts or potential approaches to the problem?

Comment: May you correct you latex?

Comment: @Bongers It means g belongs to X.I cannot do it for general lp.

Comment: You need to make your notation consistent - you're using $X$ both as a space of functions and also as the domain of those functions (in the integral). What are you assuming about the domain? Is it a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the assertion is not true: for example let $X=L^2(\mathbb R)$. Let $f(t)=1$ and define
$$
g_n(t)=\frac1t\,1_{[1,n]}.
$$
Then $g_n\in X_0$, $$\|g_n\|_2=\int_{\mathbb R}|g_n|^2\,dt=\int_{1}^n\frac1{t^2}\,dt\leq\int_1^\infty\frac1{t^2}\,dt=1.$$
But
$$
|T_f(g_n)|=\left|\int g_n\,dm\right|=\int_1^n\frac1t\,dt=\log n.
$$
So $T_f$ is not bounded.

And the converse also fails: any $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ makes $T_f$ bounded, and of course we can choose $f$ so that it is not in $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$.